# Casting the left and right numbers as integers or doubles

Tags: java, casting

How can I remove the code duplication in this code? It is trying to cast the left and right numbers as integers or doubles and then using it.

```
public Object example(Object left, Object right) {
    if(left instanceof Integer && right instanceof Integer) {
        switch (operator) {
            case ADD:
                return (Integer)left + (Integer)right;
            case SUB:
                return (Integer)left - (Integer)right;
            case MUL:
                return (Integer)left * (Integer)right;
            case DIV:
                return (Integer)left / (Integer)right;
        }
    } else if(left instanceof Double && right instanceof Double) {
        switch (operator) {
            case ADD:
                return (Double)left + (Double)right;
            case SUB:
                return (Double)left - (Double)right;
            case MUL:
                return (Double)left * (Double)right;
            case DIV:
                return (Double)left / (Double)right;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error("wrong types of arguments");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the context for this code. Where do the inputs come from? What function is this, and what is its return type?

Comment: The return type is `Object` and the inputs are `Object` too which maybe an Int or Double or something else. It throws an error incase it is not an int or double

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include the entire function?

Comment: Is `example` really the name of your function? If so, it's a terrible name.

Comment: @Mast it is just an example lol

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to do your math operations on a double.  You can use a generic method that accepts any derivative of the Number class and use the `doubleValue()` method for your calculation.  The caller of the method can cast to Integer as needed:

```
enum Operators {
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MUL,
    DIV
}

public static <T1 extends Number> Double doMath(T1 left, T1 right, Operators operator) {
    switch (operator) {
        case ADD:
            return left.doubleValue() + right.doubleValue();
        case SUB:
            return left.doubleValue() - right.doubleValue();
        case MUL:
            return left.doubleValue() * right.doubleValue();
        case DIV:
            return left.doubleValue() / right.doubleValue();
        default:
            return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could this be simplified even further? As in, could the list of operators be derived from the switch to reduce data duplication? Is there a reason you're no longer throwing an error if an unsupported operation is passed?

Comment: What's duplicated? Throwing the error was added after I posted my code. And the error is for arguments they're passing not the operation